# Anime where there is a war between guilds; the main character is evolving and creates a guild called Crow or Raven

Tags: story-identification, anime, isekai

To the best of my recollection the anime is situated in a modern world where the protagonist receives a power and has to join a battle between guilds where they win or lose points and their fights are timed.

I remember the protagonist also creates a guild called Raven something or Crow something. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  What language was it in?  Can you describe the protagonist's appearance?  Was there anything distinctive about the appearance or powers of the guild?

Comment: Is this a world where magic is real? Virtual reality? Imposed? Absent?

Comment: Sound like something similar to Sword Art Online...

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't match all the points, and it's very recent (2020), but [*Darwin's Game*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin%27s_Game#Anime) has the protagonist, Kaname Sudō, trapped in a game copy of the modern world where each of the players has a special power unlocked by their "Sigil."

Actually it's not entirely clear if the game is a true virtual reality or merely an augmented reality, since sometimes the players use their phones to view game elements, which suggests AR, but when they fight their sigils allow them to do things they couldn't do in reality, which suggests VR.  And there's apparently some leakage to the real world where some in-game effects show up in reality, so how the game works isn't very clear.

Kaname is linked into the game by a friend of his who asks for help, but dies anyway.  Kaname joins the game and is dumped into a timed deathmatch where he has to fight another player to stay alive and win points.  Kaname's sigil allows him to replicate any object he has previously held in his hand, which is handy when he needs a gun or a knife in a fight.

Kaname also decides that he doesn't want to kill, and forms the Sunset Raven clan to  oppose the vicious Eighth clan and to try to find a more peaceful way to survive in the game.

Different from your question is that the Sunset Ravens are a "clan," not a "guild."

Comment: I don't want to start an edit war over such a trifle :-), but those punctuation marks between quotes really seem strange to me. Also, is the _"trapped in a game copy the modern world"_ part missing a word?

Comment: Really?  I can't say that I've ever really noticed it being any other way.  Granted a lot of the books and magazines I've read were US-published SF, but even my UK-published copies of Adams and Pratchett use a punctuation-inside-quotes style.  (Albeit single quotes instead of double, but that looks too weird to me now because of the coder-trained part of my brain.)  Yes, a word is missing, thanks for catching it; I'll fix.